# How to check if character other than alphabet or numeric is pressed

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard-events

I have field in which only `Alphanumeric values` are allowed. I need to check a scenario where user could enter `capital letter` using "**shift**" key (**OKAY**)

> SHIFT+a =A

Also a possibility junk characters can be entered using "**shift**" key (**NOT OKAY**), like

> SHIFT+1 = !

How do I put a `validation` in a way that only characters are allowed if "SHIFT" key is pressed?

```
if(NativeEvent.getShiftKey()){
...........
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for but you might want to check if the char value of the letter is in alphabet range.

Comment: You can use regular expresion for that, only check is the character is a capital letter.

Comment: I think a good design would be let the users type whatever they want and when they enter something you don't want them to enter, remove that character from your text box/area.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect pressed keys, you can use a [KeyUpHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpHandler.html) or [KeyDownHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyDownHandler.html).

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        int pressedKey = event.getNativeKeyCode();
    }
});
```

You can use the "pressedKey" integer to see what key code user pressed. Also interesting is [KeyCodes](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyCodes.html), which has the codes for special keys.

If you want to validate user input instead, the easiest way is with [HTML5 form validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/). To implement that method, you can set up your field like this:

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.getElement().setAttribute("required", "required");
t.getElement().setAttribute("pattern", "[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

[Here's another resource](http://html5pattern.com/Names) for HTML5 form validation. [And another](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/).